# Re-use a Private Git Repo

Tags: github

I have a student Github account with 3 private repositories. I have some old project code in one of my private repositories that I no longer need to host on Github and would like to delete completely from Github (I'm intending to store that project either locally or on bitbucket, so I plan to remove everything related to that project). If I delete the repo itself, will that permanently remove that private repository and leave me with only 2 private repositories to use? Is there a way I can delete all code and all commit history while keeping that repository so I can re-use it for a different project in the future? Thanks!

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/. If you so choose you can remove the content and the repository itself. However, note that you will be able to create a new one in its place. You can have up to 3 active repos at any time. I do not think this includes forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though deleting a private repo should not lower your private repo number, you always have the possibility to:

- create new repo locally
- add a first commit
- add your existing GitHub private repo as a remote

  ```
  git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/<repo>
  ```
- force push a `master` branch to that repo

  ```
  git push --force -u origin master
  ```

All your remote repo previous commits will no longer be referenced/accessible: you will see only your new `master` branch history.